# simple calculator function in java

Tags: java

in the initial stage ,by entering + or - or other symbol,i want that operation to be done and should get me the output..instead of doing whole operations(+,-,*,/) for every number i input.

i tried many times,but still getting error ,even i am not knwing how to get the error corrected.pls provide me some suggestions..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at calculator.Calculator.main(Calculator.java:25

)

package calculator;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
    private static int valueA;
    private static int valueB;
    private static String operator;
    private static char operatorA;

    public int getValueA() {
        return valueA;
    }

    public int getValueB() {
        return valueB;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter problem.");


            valueA = keyboard.nextInt();
            valueB = keyboard.nextInt();
            operator = keyboard.next();
            operatorA = operator.charAt(0);

            int add =  '+' ;
            int minus = '-';
            int multiply = '*';
            int divide = '/';

            switch (operatorA) {
            case '+':
                add=valueA + valueB;
                System.out.println(add);
                break;

            case '-':
                minus = valueA - valueB;
                        System.out.println(minus);
                               break;

            case '*':
                multiply=valueA * valueB;
                System.out.println(multiply);
                break;

            case '/':
                divide=valueA / valueB;
                System.out.println(divide);
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("unknown operator '" + operator + "'. Please try again.");
                break;
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: it would be nice if you post the error

Comment: and the input that generates the error

Comment: @Leo ERROR is      Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at calculator.Calculator.main(Calculator.java:25

Comment: Please give us the input that gives you this error.

Comment: it would be nicer if you provide the line in your code that corresponds to 25 too

Comment: Well, @Leo, there are only two lines that it could be.  It's either the `valueA = ` line or the `valueB =` line.  I think once he/she shows us the input, it will be obvious which line it is.

Comment: I am just trying to help him/her to help us help her/him

Comment: @user3241004 i bet your number is not being interpreted correctly. I mean, if you enter a number with a space, it's not a number anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is an input mismatch. That mean that your entering something that java don't expect
As your using

```
   a.nextInt();
```

if you introduce anything else as a double (0.0....) it gives you the exception.
The easiest solution is to use

```
  a.nextDouble();
```

But of course valueA and valueB must be changed for double. It will also fix a integer conversion bug that you have.

Also you should change your variables to

```
        char add =  '+' ;
        char minus = '-';
        char multiply = '*';
        char divide = '/';
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to create a `double` variable (if you want the division operation to output a real number), and assign the result of each operation to it:

```
double result = 0.0;
switch ...
...
    result = valueA + valueB;
...
    result = (double)valueA / valueB; // note cast to double
```

Also, the error you posted indicates that the input you are giving is wrong. Since your input is:

```
valueA = keyboard.nextInt();
valueB = keyboard.nextInt();
operator = keyboard.next();
```

You must input in the following order (for example):

```
3
4
+
```

I don't think this is what you want, so you could change the order of input to

```
valueA = keyboard.nextInt();
operator = keyboard.next();
valueB = keyboard.nextInt();
```

So your input will be like

```
3
+
4
```

**Note** that you have to input numbers and operator one by one. In other words, put one number (or operator) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, put another and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.